# Importing a ruby file (or) code in python script

Tags: ruby, python-2.7, python-import

I had a ruby script which uses few ruby libraries to perform some action and gives an output. I want this ruby script output to be stored as a dictionary in a python script. For this, I want to import the ruby file similar to import python modules. Is there anyway to directly import the ruby file in python so that I can use the functionality of the ruby script inside python program instead executing the ruby script from python using modules like Popen?

Comment: Your title and text does not match. Do you want to import code or data? If the former, what does it mean to import Ruby code into Python?

Comment: @sawa: importing the functionality of the ruby code in python

Comment: @NagaLakshmi an implementation is language specific, the Python interpreter does not understand Ruby code.